# How to create a permanent table with using variable's value as table name

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a script that will populate test data in SQL Server for me. I have 5 stored procedures. First stored procedure produces ITEMs and other stored procedures create Sales Orders with those newly created ITEMs.

I don't want to explain all details not to bother you so what I want to ask you is how can I create a permanent table with name with using a variable's value as table name. BUT I don't want to create TABLE VARIABLE or TEMP TABLE, because I cannot call them from other stored procedures.

Here is what I am trying to do...

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME NVARCHAR(50)
SET @TABLENAME = 'TABLE_ITEM_1'

CREATE TABLE @TABLENAME
(
    ID INT,
    NAME NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

Then I will create TABLE_ITEM_2, TABLE_ITEM_3 and so on...

Is there way to create a table like I explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use Dynamic Query. Its the best option

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @QryStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TABLENAME = 'TABLE_ITEM_1'

SET @QryStr = '
CREATE TABLE '+@TABLENAME+'
(
ID INT,
NAME NVARCHAR(50)
)'

EXEC(@QryStr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @TABLENAME NVARCHAR(50)
SET @TABLENAME = 'TABLE_ITEM_1'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME) + '
(
ID INT,
NAME NVARCHAR(50)
)'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: there is no other way I guess. So, I should do SELECT statement with Dynamic query again?

Comment: No, as you can't specify a table name via a variable, it has be concatenated into a dynamic SQL statement to then be executed